Only Value for Which a Limit Exists and is Nonzero
I was trying to help my brother out with a problem from his calculus 1 course. The problem is a limit but I can't find any clear way way solve it.
Find $C$ such that the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg{(}{\frac{C^n}{2^{2n+2}+(-1)^n}-\frac{C^n}{4^{n+1}+2^n}\bigg{)}}$$ exists and is nonzero.
We figured out the value $C=8$ gives $\frac{1}{16}$ by some guess in check work on wolfram alpha, but no matter what algebra I try it doesn't to simplify.
Thanks in advance.

Minor nitpick: a limit does not converge. A limit either exists or it doesn't.

I don't understand what you mean. I said that C must be a value such that the limit exists. I never said converge. And limits do converge to a number if the limit exists right?

What if you do the subtraction to get one single fraction? What would the fraction be?

I tried that but, I still can't see any ways to simplify it. It gives $\frac{2^n-(-1)^n}{4^{2n+2}-(-4)^{n+1}+2^{3n+2}-(-2)^n}.$

Firstly, $C^n$ is missing. Then by dividing both the denominator and numerator by $4^{2n}$, the denominator should have a finite and non-zero limit, while the numerator should become $\left(\frac{C}{8}\right)^n\left(1-\left(-\frac12\right)^n\right)$.

$1/(4^{n+1}+2^n)=4^{-n-1}/(1+2^{-n-2})\approx4^{-n-1}(1-2^{-n-2})=4^{-n-1}-2^{-3n-4}$
